# SQLAlchemy Table classes and imports

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-class

I started a project using PostgreSQL and SQLAlchemy. Since i'm not a experienced programmer(just started using classes) and also quite new to databases i noticed some workflows i don't really understand.

What i understand up till now from classes is the following workflow:

```
# filename.py
class ClassName():
    def __init__(self):
        # do something

    def some_funcion(self, var1, var2):
        # do something with parameters

---------------------------------------

# main.py
from filename import ClassName

par1 = ...
par2 = ...

a = ClassName()
b = a.some_function(par1, par2)
```

Now i am creating tables from classes:

```
# base.py

from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
```

```
# tables.py

from base import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String


class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"
    
    a_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_column = Column(String(30))


class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = "b"
    
    b_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    b_column = Column(String(30))
```

and

```
import typing
from base import Base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from tables import A, B

metadata_obj = MetaData()

def create_tables(engine):
    session = sessionmaker()
    session.configure(bind=engine)

    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

    a = Table("a", metadata_obj, autoload_with=engine)
    b = Table("b", metadata_obj, autoload_with=engine)
    return(a, b)  # not sure return is needed


if __name__ == "__main__":
    username = "username"
    password = "AtPasswordHere!"
    dbname = "dbname"

    url = "postgresql://" + username + ":" + password + "@localhost/" + dbname
    
    engine = create_engine(url, echo=True, future=True)

    a, b = create_tables(engine)
```

Everything works fine in that it creates Table A and Table B in the database. The point i don't understand is the following:
Both my IDE(pyflake) and LGTM complain 'Tables. ... imported but not used'. **(EDIT i understand why it complains in the way it is not the normal Class flow. It is mor about Why it is not the normal class workflow)**

- Is this normal behavior for this usecase? I only see examples that make use of the above workflow
- Are there better methods to create the same results (but without the warnings)
- If this is the normal behavior: Is there an explanation for this? I didn't read it anywhere.

Comment: Because you are using declarative mapping (you have model classes that "inherit" from `declarative_base`) you don't need to create the _Tables_ `a` and `b`; they will be created automatically when `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` is called, through the model classes `A` and `B`.  You can see them by printing `A.__table__` and `B.__table__` after `create_all` has been called.

Comment: Thank you, I think i'm able to follow you. but i also have the feeling i'm missing some parts of the concept.
At the same time i miss the relation between `A` and `a`.